# How to develop multiple AngularJS apps with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

After completing the tutorial here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial, I decided to develop a new application on my local machine using AngularJS and NodeJS as a server.

I created a new folder for the new app (on the same level as the tutorial app), and used the same npm commands from the tutorial in the new folder. The problem is that when I visit the localhost:8000 address is still pointing in the previous app from the tutorial.

Since I still want to keep the tutorial app, my question is: Can I develop multiple Angular Apps from the same machine using NodeJS? How?

Comment: Change the port or stop your first app.

Comment: Why the period after "stop" ? It's confusing

Comment: @JonasGrumann typing from iPad :) is hard

Comment: Thank you @Dalorzo, I stopped the tutorial app and it worked.I had forgot that I had the tutorial app running in another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just change the starting port of your app:

In the package.json, you should have the start script

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install",
  "prestart": "npm install",
  "start": "http-server -p 8000",
}
```

Just change it to another port, for example `http-server -p 8080`

Comment: Thank you very much @edi9999, it worked perfectly! Now I can run multiple apps in different tabs.